# Rendering JSON array as a tree

Tags: javascript, array, tree, json, formatting

This code is working fine for me, but I want to simplify it.

Function `parents` is defining parents of the tree and `children` function is for representing children. `DisplayGraph()` function shows the tree in an HTML element.

```js
window.onload = function() {
            arr();
        parents();       
    };

    var array = [];



    //////////////
    var data = [
      {
        "FIELD1":1,
        "name1":"Al",
        "name2":"Newman",
        "atbat86":185,
        "hits86":37,
        "homer86":1,
        "runs86":23,
        "rbi86":8,
        "walks86":21,
        "years":2,
        "atbat":214,
        "hits":42,
        "homeruns":1,
        "runs":30,
        "rbi":9,
        "walks":24,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Mon",
        "posit86":"2B",
        "outs86":76,
        "assist86":127,
        "error86":7,
        "sal87":"70",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Min"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":2,
        "name1":"Alan",
        "name2":"Ashby",
        "atbat86":315,
        "hits86":81,
        "homer86":7,
        "runs86":24,
        "rbi86":38,
        "walks86":39,
        "years":14,
        "atbat":3449,
        "hits":835,
        "homeruns":69,
        "runs":321,
        "rbi":414,
        "walks":375,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Hou",
        "posit86":"C",
        "outs86":632,
        "assist86":43,
        "error86":10,
        "sal87":"475",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Hou"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":3,
        "name1":"Alan",
        "name2":"Trammell",
        "atbat86":574,
        "hits86":159,
        "homer86":21,
        "runs86":107,
        "rbi86":75,
        "walks86":59,
        "years":10,
        "atbat":4631,
        "hits":1300,
        "homeruns":90,
        "runs":702,
        "rbi":504,
        "walks":488,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Det",
        "posit86":"SS",
        "outs86":238,
        "assist86":445,
        "error86":22,
        "sal87":"517.143",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Det"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":4,
        "name1":"Alan",
        "name2":"Wiggins",
        "atbat86":239,
        "hits86":60,
        "homer86":0,
        "runs86":30,
        "rbi86":11,
        "walks86":22,
        "years":6,
        "atbat":1941,
        "hits":510,
        "homeruns":4,
        "runs":309,
        "rbi":103,
        "walks":207,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Bal",
        "posit86":"2B",
        "outs86":121,
        "assist86":151,
        "error86":6,
        "sal87":"700",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Bal"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":5,
        "name1":"Alex",
        "name2":"Trevino",
        "atbat86":202,
        "hits86":53,
        "homer86":4,
        "runs86":31,
        "rbi86":26,
        "walks86":27,
        "years":9,
        "atbat":1876,
        "hits":467,
        "homeruns":15,
        "runs":192,
        "rbi":186,
        "walks":161,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"LA",
        "posit86":"C",
        "outs86":304,
        "assist86":45,
        "error86":11,
        "sal87":"512.5",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"LA"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":6,
        "name1":"Alfredo",
        "name2":"Griffin",
        "atbat86":594,
        "hits86":169,
        "homer86":4,
        "runs86":74,
        "rbi86":51,
        "walks86":35,
        "years":11,
        "atbat":4408,
        "hits":1133,
        "homeruns":19,
        "runs":501,
        "rbi":336,
        "walks":194,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Oak",
        "posit86":"SS",
        "outs86":282,
        "assist86":421,
        "error86":25,
        "sal87":"750",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Oak"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":7,
        "name1":"Alvin",
        "name2":"Davis",
        "atbat86":479,
        "hits86":130,
        "homer86":18,
        "runs86":66,
        "rbi86":72,
        "walks86":76,
        "years":3,
        "atbat":1624,
        "hits":457,
        "homeruns":63,
        "runs":224,
        "rbi":266,
        "walks":263,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Sea",
        "posit86":"1B",
        "outs86":880,
        "assist86":82,
        "error86":14,
        "sal87":"480",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Sea"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":8,
        "name1":"Andre",
        "name2":"Dawson",
        "atbat86":496,
        "hits86":141,
        "homer86":20,
        "runs86":65,
        "rbi86":78,
        "walks86":37,
        "years":11,
        "atbat":5628,
        "hits":1575,
        "homeruns":225,
        "runs":828,
        "rbi":838,
        "walks":354,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Mon",
        "posit86":"RF",
        "outs86":200,
        "assist86":11,
        "error86":3,
        "sal87":"500",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Chi"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":9,
        "name1":"Andre",
        "name2":"Thornton",
        "atbat86":401,
        "hits86":92,
        "homer86":17,
        "runs86":49,
        "rbi86":66,
        "walks86":65,
        "years":13,
        "atbat":5206,
        "hits":1332,
        "homeruns":253,
        "runs":784,
        "rbi":890,
        "walks":866,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Cle",
        "posit86":"DH",
        "outs86":0,
        "assist86":0,
        "error86":0,
        "sal87":"1100",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Cle"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":10,
        "name1":"Andres",
        "name2":"Galarraga",
        "atbat86":321,
        "hits86":87,
        "homer86":10,
        "runs86":39,
        "rbi86":42,
        "walks86":30,
        "years":2,
        "atbat":396,
        "hits":101,
        "homeruns":12,
        "runs":48,
        "rbi":46,
        "walks":33,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Mon",
        "posit86":"1B",
        "outs86":805,
        "assist86":40,
        "error86":4,
        "sal87":"91.5",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Mon"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":11,
        "name1":"Andres",
        "name2":"Thomas",
        "atbat86":323,
        "hits86":81,
        "homer86":6,
        "runs86":26,
        "rbi86":32,
        "walks86":8,
        "years":2,
        "atbat":341,
        "hits":86,
        "homeruns":6,
        "runs":32,
        "rbi":34,
        "walks":8,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Atl",
        "posit86":"SS",
        "outs86":143,
        "assist86":290,
        "error86":19,
        "sal87":"75",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Atl"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":12,
        "name1":"Andy",
        "name2":"Allanson",
        "atbat86":293,
        "hits86":66,
        "homer86":1,
        "runs86":30,
        "rbi86":29,
        "walks86":14,
        "years":1,
        "atbat":293,
        "hits":66,
        "homeruns":1,
        "runs":30,
        "rbi":29,
        "walks":14,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Cle",
        "posit86":"C",
        "outs86":446,
        "assist86":33,
        "error86":20,
        "sal87":"NA",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Cle"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":13,
        "name1":"Andy",
        "name2":"Van Slyke",
        "atbat86":418,
        "hits86":113,
        "homer86":13,
        "runs86":48,
        "rbi86":61,
        "walks86":47,
        "years":4,
        "atbat":1512,
        "hits":392,
        "homeruns":41,
        "runs":205,
        "rbi":204,
        "walks":203,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"StL",
        "posit86":"RF",
        "outs86":211,
        "assist86":11,
        "error86":7,
        "sal87":"550",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Pit"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":14,
        "name1":"Argenis",
        "name2":"Salazar",
        "atbat86":298,
        "hits86":73,
        "homer86":0,
        "runs86":24,
        "rbi86":24,
        "walks86":7,
        "years":3,
        "atbat":509,
        "hits":108,
        "homeruns":0,
        "runs":41,
        "rbi":37,
        "walks":12,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"KC",
        "posit86":"SS",
        "outs86":121,
        "assist86":283,
        "error86":9,
        "sal87":"100",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"KC"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":15,
        "name1":"Barry",
        "name2":"Bonds",
        "atbat86":413,
        "hits86":92,
        "homer86":16,
        "runs86":72,
        "rbi86":48,
        "walks86":65,
        "years":1,
        "atbat":413,
        "hits":92,
        "homeruns":16,
        "runs":72,
        "rbi":48,
        "walks":65,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Pit",
        "posit86":"CF",
        "outs86":280,
        "assist86":9,
        "error86":5,
        "sal87":"100",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Pit"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":16,
        "name1":"Ben",
        "name2":"Oglivie",
        "atbat86":346,
        "hits86":98,
        "homer86":5,
        "runs86":31,
        "rbi86":53,
        "walks86":30,
        "years":16,
        "atbat":5913,
        "hits":1615,
        "homeruns":235,
        "runs":784,
        "rbi":901,
        "walks":560,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Mil",
        "posit86":"DH",
        "outs86":0,
        "assist86":0,
        "error86":0,
        "sal87":"NA",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Mil"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":17,
        "name1":"Bill",
        "name2":"Almon",
        "atbat86":196,
        "hits86":43,
        "homer86":7,
        "runs86":29,
        "rbi86":27,
        "walks86":30,
        "years":13,
        "atbat":3231,
        "hits":825,
        "homeruns":36,
        "runs":376,
        "rbi":290,
        "walks":238,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Pit",
        "posit86":"UT",
        "outs86":80,
        "assist86":45,
        "error86":8,
        "sal87":"240",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Pit"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":18,
        "name1":"Bill",
        "name2":"Buckner",
        "atbat86":629,
        "hits86":168,
        "homer86":18,
        "runs86":73,
        "rbi86":102,
        "walks86":40,
        "years":18,
        "atbat":8424,
        "hits":2464,
        "homeruns":164,
        "runs":1008,
        "rbi":1072,
        "walks":402,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Bos",
        "posit86":"1B",
        "outs86":1067,
        "assist86":157,
        "error86":14,
        "sal87":"776.667",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Bos"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":19,
        "name1":"Bill",
        "name2":"Doran",
        "atbat86":550,
        "hits86":152,
        "homer86":6,
        "runs86":92,
        "rbi86":37,
        "walks86":81,
        "years":5,
        "atbat":2308,
        "hits":633,
        "homeruns":32,
        "runs":349,
        "rbi":182,
        "walks":308,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Hou",
        "posit86":"2B",
        "outs86":262,
        "assist86":329,
        "error86":16,
        "sal87":"625",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Hou"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":20,
        "name1":"Bill",
        "name2":"Madlock",
        "atbat86":379,
        "hits86":106,
        "homer86":10,
        "runs86":38,
        "rbi86":60,
        "walks86":30,
        "years":14,
        "atbat":6207,
        "hits":1906,
        "homeruns":146,
        "runs":859,
        "rbi":803,
        "walks":571,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"LA",
        "posit86":"3B",
        "outs86":72,
        "assist86":170,
        "error86":24,
        "sal87":"850",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"LA"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":21,
        "name1":"Bill",
        "name2":"Russell",
        "atbat86":216,
        "hits86":54,
        "homer86":0,
        "runs86":21,
        "rbi86":18,
        "walks86":15,
        "years":18,
        "atbat":7318,
        "hits":1926,
        "homeruns":46,
        "runs":796,
        "rbi":627,
        "walks":483,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"LA",
        "posit86":"UT",
        "outs86":103,
        "assist86":84,
        "error86":5,
        "sal87":"NA",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"LA"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":22,
        "name1":"Bill",
        "name2":"Schroeder",
        "atbat86":217,
        "hits86":46,
        "homer86":7,
        "runs86":32,
        "rbi86":19,
        "walks86":9,
        "years":4,
        "atbat":694,
        "hits":160,
        "homeruns":32,
        "runs":86,
        "rbi":76,
        "walks":32,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Mil",
        "posit86":"UT",
        "outs86":307,
        "assist86":25,
        "error86":1,
        "sal87":"180",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Mil"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":23,
        "name1":"Billy",
        "name2":"Beane",
        "atbat86":183,
        "hits86":39,
        "homer86":3,
        "runs86":20,
        "rbi86":15,
        "walks86":11,
        "years":3,
        "atbat":201,
        "hits":42,
        "homeruns":3,
        "runs":20,
        "rbi":16,
        "walks":11,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Min",
        "posit86":"OF",
        "outs86":118,
        "assist86":0,
        "error86":0,
        "sal87":"NA",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Min"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":24,
        "name1":"Billy",
        "name2":"Hatcher",
        "atbat86":419,
        "hits86":108,
        "homer86":6,
        "runs86":55,
        "rbi86":36,
        "walks86":22,
        "years":3,
        "atbat":591,
        "hits":149,
        "homeruns":8,
        "runs":80,
        "rbi":46,
        "walks":31,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Hou",
        "posit86":"CF",
        "outs86":226,
        "assist86":7,
        "error86":4,
        "sal87":"110",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Hou"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":25,
        "name1":"Billy Jo",
        "name2":"Robidoux",
        "atbat86":181,
        "hits86":41,
        "homer86":1,
        "runs86":15,
        "rbi86":21,
        "walks86":33,
        "years":2,
        "atbat":232,
        "hits":50,
        "homeruns":4,
        "runs":20,
        "rbi":29,
        "walks":45,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Mil",
        "posit86":"1B",
        "outs86":326,
        "assist86":29,
        "error86":5,
        "sal87":"67.5",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Mil"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":26,
        "name1":"Billy",
        "name2":"Sample",
        "atbat86":200,
        "hits86":57,
        "homer86":6,
        "runs86":23,
        "rbi86":14,
        "walks86":14,
        "years":9,
        "atbat":2516,
        "hits":684,
        "homeruns":46,
        "runs":371,
        "rbi":230,
        "walks":195,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Atl",
        "posit86":"OF",
        "outs86":69,
        "assist86":1,
        "error86":1,
        "sal87":"NA",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Atl"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":27,
        "name1":"Bip",
        "name2":"Roberts",
        "atbat86":241,
        "hits86":61,
        "homer86":1,
        "runs86":34,
        "rbi86":12,
        "walks86":14,
        "years":1,
        "atbat":241,
        "hits":61,
        "homeruns":1,
        "runs":34,
        "rbi":12,
        "walks":14,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"SD",
        "posit86":"2B",
        "outs86":166,
        "assist86":172,
        "error86":10,
        "sal87":"NA",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"SD"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":28,
        "name1":"Bo",
        "name2":"Diaz",
        "atbat86":474,
        "hits86":129,
        "homer86":10,
        "runs86":50,
        "rbi86":56,
        "walks86":40,
        "years":10,
        "atbat":2331,
        "hits":604,
        "homeruns":61,
        "runs":246,
        "rbi":327,
        "walks":166,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Cin",
        "posit86":"C",
        "outs86":732,
        "assist86":83,
        "error86":13,
        "sal87":"750",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Cin"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":29,
        "name1":"Bob",
        "name2":"Boone",
        "atbat86":22,
        "hits86":10,
        "homer86":1,
        "runs86":4,
        "rbi86":2,
        "walks86":1,
        "years":6,
        "atbat":84,
        "hits":26,
        "homeruns":2,
        "runs":9,
        "rbi":9,
        "walks":3,
        "league86":"A",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"Cal",
        "posit86":"C",
        "outs86":812,
        "assist86":84,
        "error86":11,
        "sal87":"NA",
        "league87":"A",
        "team87":"Cal"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":30,
        "name1":"Bob",
        "name2":"Brenly",
        "atbat86":472,
        "hits86":116,
        "homer86":16,
        "runs86":60,
        "rbi86":62,
        "walks86":74,
        "years":6,
        "atbat":1924,
        "hits":489,
        "homeruns":67,
        "runs":242,
        "rbi":251,
        "walks":240,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"W",
        "team86":"SF",
        "posit86":"C",
        "outs86":518,
        "assist86":55,
        "error86":3,
        "sal87":"600",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"SF"
      },

      {
        "FIELD1":31,
        "name1":"Bob",
        "name2":"Dernier",
        "atbat86":324,
        "hits86":73,
        "homer86":4,
        "runs86":32,
        "rbi86":18,
        "walks86":22,
        "years":7,
        "atbat":1931,
        "hits":491,
        "homeruns":13,
        "runs":291,
        "rbi":108,
        "walks":180,
        "league86":"N",
        "div86":"E",
        "team86":"Chi",
        "posit86":"CF",
        "outs86":222,
        "assist86":3,
        "error86":3,
        "sal87":"708.333",
        "league87":"N",
        "team87":"Chi"
      }];

    //////////


    function arr(){

        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            array[i] = data[i].name1;
        }
    }




    function parents(){

        var childs = [];

            while(data.length){
            var child2 = new Object();
            child2.FIELD1 = data[0].FIELD1;
            child2.homer86 = data[0].homer86;
                    //child2.nodeDepth = 0;
            data.splice(0, 1);
            childs.push(child2);
                    child2.subChilds = children(child2, 1); // calling child function with passing parent parameter
        }

            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = displayGraph(childs);
            //displayTable(childs);
    }


    function children(node, treeSpace){

        var childs = [];

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if (data[i].homer86 == node.FIELD1){
                var child = new Object();
                child.FIELD1 = data[i].FIELD1;
                child.homer86 = data[i].homer86;
                child.treeSpace = treeSpace;
                data.splice(i, 1); // i means minimum elements should b there. and 1 element is removing
                child.subChilds = children(child, treeSpace + 1);
                childs.push(child);        
            }
            }
        return childs; 
    }



    function displayGraph(childs) {

        var space = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            space += '<br>';
            var field = childs[i].FIELD1;

            if (childs[i].subChilds.length > 0) {


                for (var j = 0; j <childs[i].treeSpace+1; j++) {
                    space += '\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0';
                }

                var name = array[field - 1];
                space += +field+ "&nbsp;" + name + displayGraph(childs[i].subChilds);

            } else {

                for (var j = 0; j <  childs[i].treeSpace; j++) {
                    space += '\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0';
                }

                var name = array[field - 1];

                space += "|------"+'&nbsp;' + field + "&nbsp;" + name;

            }
        }
        return space;
    }
```

```html
<pre id="table"></pre>
```

Comment: Running the Stack Snippet of your code shows a weird-looking "tree" — can you confirm that the output is what you wanted?

Comment: You should also ask yourself if it's necessary to post the entire JSON..

Comment: what about the edited view. Now the tree is little bit ok. But my question is how to implement this type of tree different way. I want to change the parent() and child() functions.

Answer (score 2):

### Dead code

Dead code doesn't do anything except clutter up the code and confuse readers.  Is this for debugging, or is it buggy code?  Something else, maybe?  Whatever it is, it should be removed once the code is working as expected.

```
//displayTable(childs);
```

### Indentation

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
if (data[i].homer86 == node.FIELD1){
    /* ... */
}
}
```

It is easier to see which code is in which scope if you have it indented one level per scope.  In fact, some languages take this so seriously that the level of indentation determines the scope, including Python.

Also:

```
function parents(){

    var childs = [];

        while(data.length){
        var child2 = new Object();
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

### Spacing

```
function arr(){

    /* ... */
}




function parents(){

    /* ... */
}
```

Excess spaces don't do anything except make your eye scan more of the page to find the next statement.

### Data

Your data looks awful long and similar.  Is there any official source you could pull it from instead of hard-coding it?  If there isn't, why don't you set up a separate JSON file for maintaining the data that your program reads from?

### Footnote

"Child" in plural is "Children", not "Childs".